# Can Workbox caching strategies be used to preload images before they're requested by a page?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

I'm looking to use Workbox in a Create React App project. I'm building an app for a scenario where on-load performance won't be shown to an end-user, but it's very important that everything that happens in the flow of the app doesn't show any loading or partial images.

I've been trying to understand the precaching workflow in Create React App. When I build the project, I get a precache manifest file, but loading that page doesn't start eagerly loading the assets as one might expect by the name "precaching". I guess this makes sense. You wouldn't want to preload every image in a normal web site or app.

But is there a way to force this less usual behaviour, without having to manually request every image?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is completely possible, and not that unheard of. Actually many sites decide to use pre-caching to, well, pre-cache all sorts of assets so that they're available either super quick when the browser asks for them or at all if the browser is offline. In some other situations it might be beneficial to cache stuff as the requests happen but that's not any sort of "default case" or whatever.

You can read more about Workbox pre-caching strategy here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching

I'm not familiar with Creact-React-App's implementation / use of Workbox so you better check the corresponding documentation from their part. But I *highly* suggest that you also read the whole Workbox documentation as the CRA docs will be easier to understand concept-wise after that.